# Describing a point trigonometrically

Tags: trigonometry

> Let us show that the transformation that reflects a point through a line through
>   the origin is linear. This is the transformation that takes a point on one side
>   of the line and moves it perpendicular to the line, crosses it, and continues the
>   same distance away from the line.
>   We will first assume that the transformation $T$ is linear, and thus given by a
>   matrix whose $i$th column is $T(\vec e_i)$. Again, all we have to do is figure out what
>   the $T$ does to $\vec e_1$ and $\vec e_2$. We can then apply that transformation to any point we like, by multiplying it by the matrix. There's no need to do an elaborate
>   computation for each point.
>   To obtain the first column of our matrix we thus consider where $\vec e_1$ is mapped
>   to. Suppose that our line makes an angle $\theta$ with the $x$-axis. Then $\vec e_1$ is mapped to $\begin{bmatrix}\cos2\theta\\ \sin2\theta\end{bmatrix}.$

I am struggling with seeing how they came up with the mapping in the last line of the quote above. Going by the description of that mapping, I think they treat $\vec e_1$ as a point and mark another one on the other side of the line, the same distance away. So that other point is described as $\begin{bmatrix} \cos2\theta\\ \sin2\theta\end{bmatrix}.$ I forgot a lot of trig, so I am not sure where that description comes from. Please, explain.

Comment: In love with all men or just a particular sample?

Comment: This transformation can be thought of as a rotation by theta clockwise followed by a reflection in the x axis followed by a rotaion by theta anticlockwise. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your visualization of how $\vec e_1$ is transformed geometrically is correct.

So you now have the original vector, $\vec e_1$, which we treat as a point on the $x$-axis,
you have the line of the reflection, which makes an angle $\theta$ with
the $x$-axis, and we have $T(\vec e_1),$ which is the reflected image of  $\vec e_1$.
We also have the point on the line of reflection through which $\vec e_1$
was reflected. That point is the right angle of a right triangle whose other vertices
are $\vec e_1$ and the origin of the plane;
and it is also at the right angle of a congruent right triangle whose other vertices
are $T(\vec e_1)$ and the origin of the plane.
It follows that the line from the origin through $T(\vec e_1)$ makes an angle
$\theta$ with the line of reflection, so it makes an angle $2\theta$
with the $x$-axis.

The distance from the origin to $T(\vec e_1)$ is $1$, so $T(\vec e_1)$
is a point on the unit circle at an angle of $2\theta$ from the $x$-axis.
Some people actually *define* $\sin(2\theta)$ and
$\cos(2\theta)$ in terms of the $x$- and $y$-coordinates of that point;
in any case it should not be hard to see that those are indeed that point's coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

$\vec e_1, \vec e_2$ are the $2$ trivial vectors, which together span $\mathbb R^2$. So basically:
$$
\vec e_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}, \vec e_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$

$T(\vec e_1)$ describes what happens to $\vec e_1$ when it is transformed by $T$.

You know that $T$ takes points and reflects them with a given line with angle $\theta$. So the point $(1, 0)$ in the $xy$ plane represented by $\vec e_1$ should be transformed by $T$ to the point with angle $2\theta$ with distance $1$ from the origin, or $(cos2\theta,  sin2\theta)$.

This gives you the first column of the matrix representing $T$. Try to think what $T$ does to the point $(0, 1)$.